# grunt-contrib-clean not deleting individual files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Using [load-grunt-config](https://github.com/firstandthird/load-grunt-config) to split up my Grunt configuration, I have created a `clean.js` to delete some files and folders with [grunt-contrib-clean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-clean) for a fresh rebuild:

```
module.exports = {
   deleteFiles: {
     build: [
       '<%= srcPath %>css', 
       '<%= gruntPath %>*.js', // Not working
       '<%= distPath %>css', 
       '<%= distPath %>img', 
       '<%= testPath %>*',  // Not working
       '!<%= testPath %>.scss-lint.yml', 
       'test.js' // Not working
    ]
  }
};
```

The paths have been specified within the data block of the Gruntfile:

```
srcPath: 'src/'
distPath: 'dist/'
testPath: 'test/'
gruntPath: 'grunt/'
```

When I run the cleaning task, only the specified folders are deleted, but not individual files like `*.js, *` or `test.js`

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `**` instead of one (`*`) to include all sub folders and files

**E.g** :

```js
module.exports = {
   deleteFiles: {
     build: [
       '<%= srcPath %>css', 
       '<%= gruntPath %>**/*.js', 
       '<%= distPath %>css', 
       '<%= distPath %>img', 
       '<%= testPath %>**', 
       '!<%= testPath %>.scss-lint.yml', 
       'test.js'
    ]
  }
};
```

or just specify the name of the folder with `/`.  **E.g** : `test` instead of `test/`

Concerning `test.js` file, be sure that the path is right. There is no reason why it shouldn't work